# How do you call the curve described by this equation: $A e^{-\frac{{(x-\mu)}^2}{2\sigma^2}} + C$ ? And how do you call the parameter $C$?

Tags: terminology, statistics

How do you call a curve described by this equation:

$$A e^{-\frac{{(x-\mu)}^2}{2\sigma^2}} + C.$$

It looks like a gaussian, but it's not exactly a gaussian.

And how do you call the parameter $C$? "The value at infinity"? "The shift"?

Comment: How does this arise in a physics application? Without some grounding in physics, this is purely a math question and likely to be migrated. Plus, explaining the physical application might help people understand/explain the form of the equation in a more useful way.

Comment: I would say a gaussian with an offset and $C$ the offset.

Comment: Technically it's a normal distribution, but Gaussian works as well.